# Why does frame of UIImageView change at runtime?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I set the width and the height of the UIImageView to be 320 X 320, without using autolayout n size classes.

However, when i begin running it, and i printed out the imageview.frame.height, the printout was 419

Why would the height of the frame change, especially without using autolayout?

[image]

Comment: because you use autoresizingMask :)

Comment: where did i do that?

Comment: Caleb answered before me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the view's autoresizing mask such that the view will expand along with its superview. The red arrows inside the square mean that the view will change size. The I-beams outside the square mean that the edges of the view are bounds to the edges of the superview.

[image: autosizing mask]

Comment: thank you! the autolayouts and autoresizing is super confusing indeed